# AngularJS is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn angularjs, and recently I analysed some project that I found in the web:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lnr4cf?p=preview

I downloaded it, unzipped it and opened the `index.html` file, but it wasn't working as shown in the link. I tried different browsers, same problem. Why is that? 
This is the result I'm getting. None of the links are working

[image]

Comment: what error that you getting in brower console?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, you can't mix the file:// protocol with other protocols like http:// and https:// on the same page, so your browser can't retrieve the resources it requires from parsing the HTML.

One simple solution is to serve the files statically with your own web server so you can access external resources like `angular.min.js` through http(s). If you have Python installed you can easily do this with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and then navigate to `localhost:8000` for example.

If you don't want to run a local web server, your only alternative is to download all of your dependencies to your local filesystem so you can access everything through the file:// protocol.